# Textinput focus in Python-Kivy coding

Tags: python, kivy

A beginner of python/kivy coding. I'm trying to make a question/answer- type program.

Attached code shows a simplified example of my issue. It shows text input dialog and one button dialog alternately by `remove_widget/add_widget`.
My issue is, at first, text input dialog has focus in text input, but next time it appears, it loses its focus, despite stating `self.gridlayout.txtinput.focus = True`. Any idea how I can keep its focus?

I tried adding delay time, also tried adding `txtinput.focus` description in AnswerChoiceScreen's `on_enter`, but none of them worked.

## main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

sm = ScreenManager()
class QALayout1(BoxLayout):
    pass

class QALayout2(BoxLayout):
    pass

class AnswerChoiceScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AnswerChoiceScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.gridlayout = None
        self.gridlayout = QALayout2()
        self.add_widget(self.gridlayout)

    def _create_layout(self):
        if self.gridlayout is not None:
            self.remove_widget(self.gridlayout)
        self.add_widget(self.gridlayout)

    def button1_clicked(self, *args):
        if self.gridlayout is not None:
            self.remove_widget(self.gridlayout)
        self.gridlayout = QALayout2()
        self.add_widget(self.gridlayout)
        self.gridlayout.txtinput.focus = True

    def buttonOK_clicked(self, *args):
        if self.gridlayout is not None:
            self.remove_widget(self.gridlayout)
        self.gridlayout = QALayout1()
        self.add_widget(self.gridlayout)

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):  
        self.anschoi = AnswerChoiceScreen(name = 'anschoi') 
        sm.add_widget(self.anschoi)
        sm.current = 'anschoi'
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    myApp().run()
```

## my.kv

```
<AnswerChoiceScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 10,40,10,40 
        spacing: 40 

<QALayout1>:
    Button1:
        id: btn1
        text: 'OK'
        on_press: root.parent.button1_clicked()  


<QALayout2>:
    txtinput: txtinput
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput:
        id: txtinput
        text: ''
        multiline: False
        focus: True
    ButtonOK:
        id:ButtonOK
        text: 'OK'
        on_press: root.parent.buttonOK_clicked()  

<Button0@Button>:
<Button1@Button>:
<ButtonOK@Button>:
```

Comment: Why not use self.gridlayout.ids["textinput"]

Comment: Just because Kivy reference manual suggests to use PropertyObjects rather than ids library solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange enough, all you need to do is to change

```
<QALayout1>:
    Button1:
        id: btn1
        text: 'OK'
        on_press: root.parent.button1_clicked()
```

to:

```
<QALayout1>:
    Button1:
        id: btn1
        text: 'OK'
        on_release: root.parent.button1_clicked()
```

Changing `on_press` to `on_release`. I believe it has to do with the focus of your `TextInput` being set on the `on_touch_down` (`on_press`) event, but then it loses focus due to the `on_touch_up` (`on_release`) event. So using the `on_release` avoids that problem. You can see this happen, by running your original code and pressing that `OK` button, but don't release it. The `TextInput` will have focus until you release your mouse button.

And you don't even need the line:

```
self.gridlayout.txtinput.focus = True
```

Comment: Wow, impressive! I was spending 3 days struggling with this problem, but was with no good result. Your solution works fine! Thank you for your valuable comment!